# How to install & configure mod_wsgi for py3

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, apache2, mod-wsgi

I installed & configured mod_wsgi for python2.7 but now I would also like to have mod_wsgi for py3

I'm in ubuntu 12.04
My apache conf file looks like this for py2.7 :

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/my_web>
    WSGIProcessGroup my_web
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now I would like to install mod_wsgi for python3.

I think I have to do apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

But I can't find any instruction on how to configure mod_wsgi for py3.
a) Can I keep mod_wsgi for py2.7 or do I need to remove it for apache to work with mod_wsgi_py3?
b) What do I need to include in my apache conf?

Comment: Heap installed like that , it's a package instalation with apache2 , you don't have to configured it again.

Comment: You can't have both libapache2-modwsgi and libapache2-modwsgi-py3 installed, at least in Debian. I assume it's the same case in Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is one or the other.

Comment: I think your mistake it was to omit the mod_wsgi tag -- the developer appears to be monitoring that tag. I've just asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674644/installing-mod-wsgi-for-python3-on-ubuntu

Comment: drabo2005 actually answered me. You just have to do apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 and it will overwrite the mod-wsgi for py2.7. That configure file worked fine.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`

This will replace libapache2-mod-wsgi and will restart the apache service.

More specific instructions (Django) are available for here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Thanks. It may be 5 years old, yet it's still what I needed on Ubu20

Answer (score 6):

It is incorrect to say you do not need to install it again. Graham Dumpleton (the author of the mod_wsgi module) addressed the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194594/django-plugged-into-apache-not-working-like-django-standalone).

Short answer - you will need to install the mod_wsgi compiled for your updated Python. I had the very same issue - as far as I can remember you need to get the correct pip for your Python version and run something along the lines of this:

```
sudo pip3.x install --target=/path/to/python3.x/site-packages mod_wsgi
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using virtualenvs (which you should) you would simply build one out for the version of python you want to build mod_wsgi for.

```
$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 myvenv
```

Then

```
(myvenv) $ pip install mod_wsgi
```

will build a Python3 version for you.

Comment: Bear in mind (as I got bitten by this) that you will need to have apache2-dev installed so that the apxs tool is available. Without this, using pip to install mod_wsgi will fail.

Comment: .. and python-dev or python3-dev depending on which version of Python you are building against.